# Confused regarding order output of confusion matrix

Tags: python, classification, svm, confusion-matrix

I used SVM classifier for binary classification. We trained the models using data samples for legitimate users (labeled with "0", positive class) and undesired users (labeled with"1", negative class).

when testing the model I also labeled the samples of legitimate users with zeros and undesired users with ones.
X_test has 5 data samples (first 5 rows) of legitimates labeled with zeros and other 5 samples (last 5 rows) of undesired users lebeld with ones. This is the labels y_test= [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]

Then, I classified using this:

```
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

the output y_pred = [0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]

In our work, we considered:

> > (True positive)  TP is the legitimate user's samples (with label zero in y_test) that correctly classified as legitimates (with label zero in y_pred).

> > (False Negative)  FN is the legitimate user's samples (with label zero in y_test) that incorrectly classified as undesired users (with label one in y_pred).

> > (True negative)  TN is the undesired user's samples (with label one in y_test) that correctly classified as undesired (with label one in y_pred).

> > (False positive)  FP is the undesired user's samples (with label one in y_test) that incorrectly classified as legitimates(with label zero in y_pred).

But, when is input y_test and y_pred to confusion matrix using:

```
print('Outcome confusion_matrix values : \n', confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

the confusion gives : [4 1][2 3]

In the confusion matrix documentation, they say the order is [TN FP][FN TP]

However, this is the opposite of the order used in our work according to our definitions of TP, FN, FP, TN that we used.
In our work:

```
0--> 0 = TP; 
0--> 1 = FN;
1--> 0 = FP;
1--> 1 = TN;
```

Thus, I swiped and considered TP =4, FN = 1, FP = 2, TN=3, to match the definitions of our work.

Am I write? I am so confused, please help me to clarify this.

Comment: So in that case why don't you write your own confusion matrix?

Comment: @David, it seems I used my own confusion matrix, right? Is my calculation correct, please?

Comment: It mostly depends on what you define as positive/negative. Based on your definitions you are correct, but the matrix will stay the same. just the TP/FN.. will be different

Comment: Exactly! It depends on how you define positive and negative. For you, legitimate user maybe positive whereas someone else may consider an undesired user as positive(sorta like medical diagnosis)

Comment: Yes, you are right, the matrix's values will stay the same. Just the definition of positives (0) and negatives (1) that I considered are opposite those in the confusion matrix.

Comment: @sai, NO NO, in our work, the legitimate users (class 0) are considered positives and undesired users (class 1) are considered negatives. This is the opposite of a medical diagnosis. I mean if a legitimate user (class 0) has wrongly classified by our system as an undesired user (class 1) this is called False-negative (FN) because a positive sample (legitimate user) wrongly classified as a negative user (i.e. undesire). Am I correct with this approach?

Comment: I think you are correct! Best way to verify your interpretation is manually clacukate the confusion matrix for a small number of samples. I always do that.

Comment: Yeah, I did, I am correct but just I was needed to confirm this with others. Thanks